# Getting "Could not find a version of package .." in composer inspite of having tags in Github branch of package

Tags: php, git, composer-php, packagist

I am learning on how to upload a package on packagist.org. I created a github repository for testing with composer.json file -
https://github.com/perials/check
 and a composer package using this github repository - https://packagist.org/packages/perials/check

When I try to install this package using `composer require perials/check` I get below error

```
[InvalidArgumentException]                                              
Could not find a version of package perials/check matching your minimum-stability (stable). Require it with an explicit version constraint allowing its desired stability.
```

From what I read in other related questions on SO this error occurs if there are no stable releases of github branch. But thing is that I already have some releases.

I also tried `composer require perials/check:dev-master` and `composer require perials/check:7.1.0` but then I get below error

```
[InvalidArgumentException]             
Could not find package perials/check.  

Did you mean this?                     
perials/check
```

Comment: It is looking for an @stable tagged release that you do not appear to have.  You probably need to do something like `composer require perials/check:dev-master@dev`

Comment: Both dev-master and 7.1.0 worked for me with @dev

Comment: Does something like `composer require perials/check ^7.1.0` work?

Comment: Issue is fixed now. As Md Abu Ahsan Basir pointed out it was perhaps due to some issue with Singapore mirror. But thank you guys for the suggestions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It was an issue with Singapore mirror for the packagist metadata. Now it should be resolved. https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/8347#issuecomment-537176755

If still not solve your issue please add `"minimum-stability": "dev"` in your composer.json

```
{
    "name": "perials/check",
    "description": "Package for testing packagist",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Perials",
            "email": "info@perials.com"
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {"Abc\\": "src/xyz"}
    },
    "require": {},
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

Comment: It's working now (without adding `"minimum-stability": "dev"`). Assuming you are right; it was related to issue with packagist metadata with Singapore mirror. Thanks.

Comment: For safety, you should use "minimum-stability": "dev" although your package working without it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am also learning how to create packages and have the same problem, but in my case I created a v1.0.0 tag for my package and that solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can accept no stable version packages. See composer in docs (https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#package-links).

Paste piece here for convinience:

> You can apply them to a constraint, or apply them to an empty constraint if you want to allow unstable packages of a dependency for example.

`composer.json`:

```
{
    "require": {
        "monolog/monolog": "1.0.*@beta",
        "acme/foo": "@dev"
    }
}
```

In your case you would do:

```
{
    "require": {
        "perials/check": "7.1.0@dev"
    }
}
```

and then run `rm composer.lock; composer install`.